# When i want to commit staged/unstaged to a new branch, do i need to unstage everything?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to take a bunch of committed work and commit it to a new branch.

I saw some posts saying that if you have unstaged changes, you can change branch easily and then just `git add <files>`.  My question is, What happens about files staged to be committed?  Should I unstage them prior to changing branch?

Right now I have some new files staged to be committed.  I thought that doing the command `git reset head *` would have negative side effects like wiping all of my unstaged files.

What is the best way to go about this?

```
#unstage
#change branch
#stage
#commit
#push    (im not sure if i should also define a new remote or not)
```

Comment: You do not need to do anything. If you just `git checkout -b some_new_branch` then all the commits will be present from the branch you were previously on.

Comment: oh ok.  I thought that staged commits to a branch are linked to that branch for some reason.  This is the key as to why i was worried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git checkout -b new-branch

git commit -m 'my new branch'

Answer (score 0):

You could stash you changes 
- git stash

Create your new branch
- git checkout -b new-branch

Unstash changes
- git stash pop

Add to stage
- git add .